# I am looking for level A1/A2 German books in PDF format

Tags: learning, resource, book, online-resource

I want to learn German again from starting level. So I need simple books for the levels **A1** and **A2**. Also, I want these in PDF format.

Can you suggest me some resources for this issue?

Comment: I have no idea what they are worth: https://www.learngermanonline.org/free-downloadable-pdfs/ or https://www.learn-german-online.net/en/learning-german-resources/free-german-lessons-a1.htm is what I found just googling for it. Or wikibooks. I guess you did the same that is why you found nothing useful and ask here?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Thanks for posted links. It is a good thing to update my knowledge about german grammar. :-)

Comment: It really depends a lot from what is your previous training. What other languages do you know (except obviously English). How experienced are you in self-studying. What are your interests?

Answer (score 1):

Books like short stories for German A1/A2 learners are not available as PDF. You just can buy them as real book or audio book or for digital reader devices in their appropriate format. Just for copyright reasons.