# German textbook series for all levels (at least A1-B2) with lots of exercises

Tags: learning, resource, book

Hello my school is looking for new textbooks.

I really like the style of textbook when you have doublepage with text exercises, few new works and separate workbook where you can practise at home. I hate textbook where they throw at you 2 A4 of vocabulary and no exercises to practice them.

We would need textbook series that goes from total beginner A1 to B2.

I thought about something similar to insight from oxford press for english

Do you have any recommendations?

Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Which sources did you try and where do they _not fit_? Here is a similiar question: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/57998/36160 or ... well do a search on German.SE or at least internet search engine .... So please, consider a search like on any publisher you call legit. Or Goethe-Institut. Or ... I don't know, long time ago I learned itin School and still was my mother tongue, so your demand may vary (how old are your learners?)

Comment: PS "all levels" would include C-levels as well.

Comment: We currently use https://www.amazon.com/Studio-21-Deutschbuch-English-speaking-learners/dp/3065201054. Problem with this textbook is that there aren't enough excersises and we are missing workbook. By all levels I mean from A1 at least to B2. I'm asking here because on the market there are many textbooks but problem is to choose good one. Btw what is the German.Se? I cannot find website of that name. Thanks for answers

Comment: please include your search/ status quo into the question. German.SE is short for German.StackExchange.com - the site you wrote your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Shaum's Outline for German is a must resource in my opinion.
Perhaps one text does not satisfy all needs, but this book should be required in my opinion at least as a supplemental book. Perhaps that would fix any issues you'd have with the main textbook you are considering.